# split a file keeping some columns

Tags: bash, awk

I need to split a file with ~5million rows based on some columns, i.e, I need to keep some columns on the different chunks. I am aware of split command for row-wise splitting, but don't know if there is any similar function to split column-wise with as I would like to. My file has 196 `ANN` columns

```
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN1 ANN2 ANN3 
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 0 0 0  
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 0 1 0 
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 0 0 1
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1 1 1
```

The desired output will be

```
#chunk1
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN1
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 0   
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 0  
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 0 
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1 

#chunk2
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN2 
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 0  
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 1 
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 0
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1

#chunk3
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN3 
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 0  
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 0 
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1
```

The names of my `ANN` columns are not like `ANN1` `ANN2`, the names are quite different to each other, I have just used `ANN` for simplicity.

The speed would be an issue, since the file is quite huge

UPDATE: if it would be possible I would like to split the files every 10 or 20 ANN columns (the total number of ANN is 196)

Comment: they are separated by space (space delimited)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
% cat script.awk
{
  for (i=8;i<=NF;i++) {
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $i >> "chunk"(i-7)".txt"
  }
}
```

This will write 8 columns for each `ANN` columns into `chunk1.txt`, `chunk2.txt`, ... `chunkN.txt` (First 7 and then one `ANN` column). Run it with:

```
awk -f script.awk input_file
```

I assume that `>>` will open a file handle, append the line and then close it. So it's properly possible to optimize it.

Comment: thanks @andlrc, would it be the `script.awk` very different if instead of splitting just one ANN column at a time, I would like to split 10 in each chunk?

Comment: @user2380782, for future potential answerers (such as myself), all your requirements need to go up in the question.

Comment: thanks @glennjackman and sorry for not doing like that, should I update my question?

Answer (score 3):

A solution with perl:

The initial file, with a few extra columns

```
$ cat file
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN1 ANN2 ANN3 ANN4 ANN5 ANN6 ANN7 ANN8
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 0 0 0 a b c d e
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 0 1 0 f g h i j
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 0 0 1 k l m n o
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1 1 1 p q r s t
```

A perl script to split it up

```
$ perl -alne '
      $n=4;  # how many data columns to put into the "split" files
      for ( ($i,$j)=(7,1); $i < @F; $i+=$n,$j++ ) {
          open($fh{$j}, ">", "file.$j") unless $fh{$j};
          @data = (@F[0..6], @F[$i .. $i+$n-1]); 
          print {$fh{$j}} "@data"; 
      }
  ' file
```

The results

```
$ cat file.1
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN1 ANN2 ANN3 ANN4
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 0 0 0 a
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 0 1 0 f
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 0 0 1 k
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 1 1 1 p

$ cat file.2
SNPID CHR POS Z F N LNBF ANN5 ANN6 ANN7 ANN8
rs367896724 1 10177 0 0 0 -3.36827717630604 b c d e
rs555500075 1 10352 0 0 0 -2.30999509213213 g h i j
rs575272151 1 11008 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 l m n o
rs544419019 1 11012 0 0 0 -1.14611711529388 q r s t
```